# Hyundai PID abbreviations

Tags: hyundai

i cannot find engine temp and fuel trims on my scanner for Hyundai. what are the PID abbreviations for engine temp and fuel trims on a scanner for Hyundai

Answer (score 1):

ECT, LTFT, STFT

The PID abbreviations are defined by the OBD [II] standard, not by Hyundai.